# In MySQL how to join tables using their names which are based on column values of another table?

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I've customized `OpenCart 3` in a way that customer be able to follow `category` and `manufacturer`.
In home page, each customer will see a list of products based on what he/she followed.
To save data size, I've used abbreviation for category and customer as `c` and `m`, and that a big problem for me to make a join query.
At the other hand, I would like to load a list product_ids order by `date_modified` first, then in the time of `scrolling down`, load the full product information as requested.

**UPDATED FIDDLE**
SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/831301/2

```
CREATE TABLE follow (
    `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `item_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`,`item_id`,`item_type`)
)

INSERT INTO follow (customer_id, item_id, item_type) VALUES
(1, 1, 'm'), 
(1, 2, 'm'),
(1, 3, 'm'),
(1, 1, 'c'),
(1, 2, 'c'),
(1, 3, 'c');

-- `m` stands for `manufacturer`
-- 'c' stands for `category`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
    `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_description` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`language_id`),
    KEY `name` (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `top` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`parent_id`),
    KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `manufacturer` (
    `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`manufacturer_id`)
)
```

To do this I tried to make it simpler for myself but the result is wrong:

**UPDATED QUERY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, p.price, procats.category_id FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT pc.product_id, pc.category_id FROM follow f2 
        LEFT JOIN product_to_category pc on (f2.item_id = pc.category_id) 
        WHERE f2.item_type = 'c') AS procats ON (procats.product_id = p.product_id)
    order by p.price
```

**UPDATE** : Result of my query:

```
product_id  price   category_id
9   15  (null)
1   15  1
1   15  2
1   15  3
2   15  1
3   15  2
4   15  (null)
5   15  3
6   15  (null)
7   15  (null)
8   15  (null)
```

In addition I'd highly appreciate if you give me any suggestion about improving the whole structure and correcting possible mistakes.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: a list of product_ids with lots of nulls as category_ids

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: I updated my question.

Comment: you can create the query based on the customers' choice using a prepared statement method in MySQL. While using that you can compare the customer follow and prepare the query accordingly and execute for the result. There is another way to use case when to join statement to make a conditional join. let me know what you need a bit more detail for the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of two follow tables, one for manufacturer, one for categories, you've decided for only one, which means your follow table points to a "thing" you call item, which can be either manufacturer or category and the DBMS cannot see what you actually point to and help you with consistency checks.

Now you want a list of products that a customer follows via manufactorer or category. So select from `product` and use `IN` or `EXISTS` to restrict this to products being followed by the customer:

```
select *
from product
where manufacturer_id in 
(
  select item_id from follow where item_type = 'm' and customer_id = 1
)
or product_id in 
(
  select product_id from product_to_category where category_id in
    (select item_id from follow where item_type = 'c' and customer_id = 1)
)
order by date_modified desc;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/831301/11

If you want products with their categories instead:

```
select *
from product p
join product_to_category pc on pc.product_id = p.product_id
join category c on c.category_id = pc.category_id
where p.manufacturer_id in 
(
  select item_id from follow where item_type = 'm' and customer_id = 1
)
or c.category_id in 
(
  select item_id from follow where item_type = 'c' and customer_id = 1
)
order by date_modified desc;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/831301/17

Comment: It's going to be an "expensive" query no ?

Comment: @Thorsten: Do you have any suggestion for what I'm going to do? Is my method correct?

Comment: Expensive? Well, `OR` is always a tad expensive, yes. Apart from that make sure to have an index on `follow(customer_id, item_type)` and one on `product(manufacturer_id)`.

Comment: I'd prefer two follow tables, one for manufacturers, one for categories. As is, you could enter manufacturers and categories in your follow table that don't exist. I like it much better to have my database with proper foreign key constraints, so such errors cannot happen.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Thanks a lot for your suggestion and perfect answer. I'm going to do as you suggested.

Comment: @Thorstenkettner: in case of using two separate tables for follow, still can I use "where-in" or there is a better approach? I'd appreciate if you add it to the answer if is different.

Comment: You would still use almost the same query. The main advantage is that the DBMS can guarantee data consistency. And querying the data may be a tad faster.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use column related  to left joined  table in where condition ( work as a inner join ) you are using `WHERE f2.item_type = 'c'` .. move this condition in ON clause

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        p.product_id
        , p.model
        , procats.category_id 
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN  (
        SELECT DISTINCT pc.product_id, pc.category_id 
        FROM follow f2 
        LEFT JOIN product_to_category pc on f2.item_id = pc.category_id  
               AND  f2.item_type = 'c'
        ) AS procats ON procats.product_id = p.product_id
    order by p.model
```

Comment: I tried it, but I got nulls again. After all, my query is not correct anyway, because it returns products of categories followed by customer. Probably I should use UNION to get Manufacturer products, right?